# What's the difference between PHP's DOM and SimpleXML extensions?

Tags: php, simplexml, domdocument

I'm failing to comprehend why do we need 2 XML parsers in PHP.

Can someone explain the difference between those two?

Answer (score 111, accepted):

In a nutshell:

**SimpleXml**

- is for simple XML and/or simple UseCases
- limited API to work with nodes (e.g. cannot program to an interface that much)
- all nodes are of the same kind (element node is the same as attribute node)
- nodes are magically accessible, e.g. `$root->foo->bar['attribute']`

**DOM**

- is for any XML UseCase you might have
- [is an implementation of the W3C DOM API](http://www.w3.org/DOM/) (found implemented in many languages)
- differentiates between various Node Types (more control)
- much more verbose due to explicit API (can code to an interface)
- can parse broken HTML
- allows you to use PHP functions in XPath queries

Both of these are based on [libxml](http://xmlsoft.org/) and can be influenced to some extend by the [libxml functions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.libxml.php)

---

**Personally**, I dont like SimpleXml too much. That's because I dont like the implicit access to the nodes, e.g. `$foo->bar[1]->baz['attribute']`. It ties the actual XML structure to the programming interface. The one-node-type-for-everything is also somewhat unintuitive because the behavior of the SimpleXmlElement magically changes depending on it's contents.

<sup>For instance, when you have `<foo bar="1"/>` the object dump of `/foo/@bar` will be identical to that of `/foo` but doing an echo of them will print different results. Moreover, because both of them are SimpleXml elements, you can call the same methods on them, but they will only get applied when the SimpleXmlElement supports it, e.g. trying to do `$el->addAttribute('foo', 'bar')` on the first SimpleXmlElement will do nothing. Now of course it is correct that you cannot add an attribute to an Attribute Node, but the point is, an attribute node would not expose that method in the first place.</sup>

**But that's just my 2c. Make up your own mind** :)

---

On a **sidenote**, there is not two parsers, but [a couple more in PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/en/refs.xml.php). SimpleXml and DOM are just the two that parse a document into a tree structure. The others are either pull or event based parsers/readers/writers.

Also see my answer to

- [Best XML Parser for PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/188414/best-xml-parser-for-php/3616044#3616044)

Comment: Nice answer. To make it complete, you can add `XMLReader` http://php.net/xmlreader ;) Its faster and consumes not that much memory (its stream-based), but its more difficult to use. -- Just read your answer to the end: You mentioned it. ^^

Comment: Actually, if you run XPath to get attributes, the objects that are returned can simply be cast as a string if you want their value, e.g. `$attrs = $sxe->xpath('/foo/bar/@baz'); echo $attrs[0];`

Comment: @Josh which makes it even more unintuitive because the SimpleXml element is changing it's behavior depending on it's internal state. But I get a feeling of DejaVu here ;)

Comment: I understand, and agree to an extent with, your criticism of SimpleXML's one class for all nodes design, but the fact that "the object dump ... will be identical" is a limitation of the object dump (by which I imagine you mean `print_r` or `var_dump`), not the object - although I guess that's still a limitation of the library.

Answer (score 45):

*I'm going to make the shortest answer possible so that beginners can take it away easily. I'm also slightly simplifying things for shortness' sake. Jump to the end of that answer for the overstated TL;DR version.*

---

DOM and SimpleXML **aren't actually two different parsers**. The real parser is [libxml2](http://xmlsoft.org/), which is used internally by DOM and SimpleXML. So DOM/SimpleXML are just two ways to use the same parser and they provide ways to convert [one object](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/function.dom-import-simplexml.php) to [another](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-import-dom.php).

**SimpleXML** is intended to be very simple so it has a small set of functions, and it is focused on **reading and writing data**. That is, you can easily read or write a XML file, you can [update some values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4748014/updating-xml-node-with-php/4748307#4748307) or remove some nodes ([with some limitations!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4730764/php-simplexml-remove-items-with-for)), and that's it. **No fancy manipulation**, and you don't have access to the less common node types. For instance, SimpleXML cannot create a CDATA section although it can read them.

**DOM** offers a **full-fledged implementation of the [DOM](http://www.w3.org/DOM/)** plus a couple of non-standard methods such as [appendXML](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/domdocumentfragment.appendxml.php). If you're used to manipulate DOM in Javascript, you'll find exactly the same methods in PHP's DOM. There's basically **no limitation** in what you can do and it evens handles HTML. The flipside to this richness of features is that it is **more complex** and more verbose than SimpleXML.

---

### Side-note

People often wonder/ask what extension they should use to handle their XML or HTML content. Actually the choice is easy because there isn't much of a choice to begin with:

- if you need to deal with HTML, you don't really have a choice: you have to use DOM
- if you have to do anything fancy such as moving nodes or appending some raw XML, again you pretty much *have* to use DOM
- if all you need to do is read and/or write some basic XML (e.g. exchanging data with an XML service or reading a RSS feed) then you can use either. [Or](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/function.dom-import-simplexml.php) [both](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-import-dom.php).
- if your XML document is so big that it doesn't fit in memory, you can't use either and you have to use [XMLReader](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/book.xmlreader.php) which is *also* based on libxml2, is even more annoying to use but still [plays nice with others](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/xmlreader.expand.php)

---

### TL;DR

- SimpleXML is super easy to use but only good for 90% of use cases.
- DOM is more complex, but can do everything.
- XMLReader is super complicated, but uses very little memory. Very situational.

Comment: thanks Josh. for those whore are like WTF is tldr thing: "Too long; didn't read".

Comment: Please remove **complicated** or mark it as personal opinion. DOM is **not** complicated. It's clean and explicit API makes it easy to grasp, even for beginners. Unlike SimpleXml, where you have to guess what it does due to the reasons I've pointed out in my answer. Just because something is verbose doesnt mean it is more complicated. On the contrary. Apart from that, good write-up.

Comment: Although the TL;DR section is said to be overstated, I wouldn't want to argue over the meaning or the weight of a word, so how about settling for saying that DOM is "more complex"? My dictionary seems to fully support that construct.

Comment: Regarding HTML, you can load an HTML document with the DOM and then use `simplexml_import_dom` to traverse it with SimpleXML, so it's not quite true that you have to use DOM.

Comment: For big XML documents you can combine XMLReader with SimpleXML andutilize best from both worlds. Simplicity and small memmory footprint. Just find desired tag (item, row, product...) with XMLReader and expand it to SimpleXML object to easily work with.

Answer (score 4):

#### Which DOMNodes can be represented by SimpleXMLElement?

The biggest difference between the two libraries is that SimpleXML is mainly a single class: `SimpleXMLElement`. In contrast, the DOM extension has many classes, most of them a subtype of `DOMNode`.

So one core question when comparing those two libraries is which of the many classes DOM offers can be represented by a `SimpleXMLElement` in the end?

The following is a comparison table containing those `DOMNode` types that are actually useful as long as dealing with XML is concerned (useful node types). Your mileage may vary, e.g. when you need to deal with DTDs for example:

```
+-------------------------+----+--------------------------+-----------+
| LIBXML Constant         |  # | DOMNode Classname        | SimpleXML |
+-------------------------+----+--------------------------+-----------+
| XML_ELEMENT_NODE        |  1 | DOMElement               |    yes    |
| XML_ATTRIBUTE_NODE      |  2 | DOMAttr                  |    yes    |
| XML_TEXT_NODE           |  3 | DOMText                  |  no [1]   |
| XML_CDATA_SECTION_NODE  |  4 | DOMCharacterData         |  no [2]   |
| XML_PI_NODE             |  7 | DOMProcessingInstruction |    no     |
| XML_COMMENT_NODE        |  8 | DOMComment               |    no     |
| XML_DOCUMENT_NODE       |  9 | DOMDocument              |    no     |
| XML_DOCUMENT_FRAG_NODE  | 11 | DOMDocumentFragment      |    no     |
+-------------------------+----+--------------------------+-----------+
```

- `[1]`: SimpleXML abstracts text-nodes as the string value of an element (compare
               [`__toString`](http://www.php.net/language.oop5.magic#object.tostring)). This does only work well when an
               element contains text only, otherwise text-information can get lost.
- `[2]`: Every XML Parser can expand CDATA nodes when loading the document. SimpleXML expands these when the
               [`LIBXML_NOCDATA` option](http://php.net/libxml.constants) is used with
               [`simplexml_load_*` functions](http://php.net/simplexml_load_file) or
               the [constructor](http://php.net/simplexmlelement.construct). (Option works as well with
               [`DOMDocument::loadXML()`](http://php.net/domdocument.loadxml))

As this table shows, SimpleXML has really limited interfaces compared to DOM. Next to the ones in the table, `SimpleXMLElement` also abstracts access to children and attribute lists as well as it provides traversal via element names (property access), attributes (array access) as well as being a [`Traversable`](http://php.net/Traversable) iterating it's "own" children (elements or attributes) and offering namespaced access via the `children()` and `attributes()` methods.

As long as all this magic interface it's fine, however it can not be changed by extending from SimpleXMLElement, so as magic as it is, as limited it is as well.

To find out which nodetype a SimpleXMLElement object represents, please see:

- [How to tell apart SimpleXML objects representing element and attribute?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/724935/367456)

[DOM follows here the DOMDocument Core Level 1 specs](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17340952/367456). You can do nearly every imaginable XML handling with that interface. However it's only Level 1, so compared with modern DOMDocument Levels like 3, it's somewhat limited for some cooler stuff. Sure SimpleXML has lost here as well.

SimpleXMLElement allows casting to subtypes. This is very special in PHP. DOM allows this as well, albeit it's a little bit more work and a more specific nodetype needs to be chosen.

[XPath 1.0](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/) is supported by both, the result in SimpleXML is an `array` of `SimpleXMLElements`, in DOM a `DOMNodelist`.

`SimpleXMLElement` supports casting to string and array (json), the DOMNode classes in DOM do not. They offer casting to array, but only like any other object does (public properties as keys/values).

#### Common usage patterns of those two extensions in PHP are:

- You normally start to use SimpleXMLElement. Your level of knowledge about XML and XPath is on an equally low level.
- After fighting with the magic of its interfaces, a certain level of frustration is reached sooner or later.
- You discover that you can import `SimpleXMLElement`s into DOM and vice-versa. You learn more about DOM and how to use the extension to do stuff you were not able (or not able to find out how) to do with `SimpleXMLElement`.
- You notice that you can load HTML documents with the DOM extension. And invalid XML. And do output formatting. Things SimpleXMLElement just can't do. Not even with the dirty tricks.
- You probably even switch to DOM extension fully because at least you know that the interface is more differentiated and allows you to do stuff. Also you see a benefit in learning the DOM Level 1 because you can use it as well in Javascript and other languages (a huge benefit of DOM extension for many).

You can have fun with both extensions and I think you should know both. The more the better. All the libxml based extensions in PHP are very good and powerful extensions. And on Stackoverflow under the [php](/questions/tagged/php) tag there is a good tradition to cover these libraries well and also with detailed information.

Comment: Note [2] regarding CDATA is incorrect/misleading: CDATA nodes are **always** rolled up in the same way as (and along with) text nodes when using `__toString()`; the `LIBXML_NOCDATA` option only makes a difference when "re-serializing" the object - either using `->asXML()`, or outputting the whole structure with `print_r()`, `json_encode()`, etc.

Comment: @IMSoP: Well as SimpleXMLElement does take care of the array-cast (and not only the string cast), it shows that the array cast *has problems* with CDATA elements. You can find my detailed analysis in [***SimpleXML and JSON Encode in PHP – Part II***](http://hakre.wordpress.com/2013/07/09/simplexml-and-json-encode-in-php-part-ii/) which was a reason of my answer here, too. json_encode makes use of array casting internally, so don't get irritated by the `json_encode()` function that you find there,  too, as you make that one an exclusion, I include it (indirectly) because of array casting.

Comment: @demo: https://eval.in/37221 - problems might be the wrong term, let's say, it has similar issues as when deciding on how to traverse all those children. But [2] is still correct. Any XML parser is allowed to expand those CDATA elements when the document is loaded. For streamlining reasons (e.g. if you don't want to cast elements to string), you can do this by taking that option constant. That's all I meant so I don't think this statement is wrong at all. Also thanks for your review!

Answer (score 3):

As others have pointed out, the DOM and SimpleXML extensions are not strictly "XML parsers", rather they are different interfaces to the structure generated by the underlying libxml2 parser.

The SimpleXML interface treats XML as a serialized data structure, in the same way you would treat a decoded JSON string. So it provides quick access to the *contents* of a document, with emphasis on accessing elements by name, and reading their attributes and text content (including automatically folding in entities and CDATA sections). It supports documents containing multiple namespaces (primarily using the `children()` and `attributes()` methods), and can search a document using an XPath expression. It also includes support for *basic* manipulation of the content - e.g. adding or overwriting elements or attributes with a new string.

The DOM interface, on the other hand, treats XML as a structured *document*, where the representation used is as important as the data represented. It therefore provides much more granular and explicit access to different types of "node", such as entities and CDATA sections, as well as some which are ignored by SimpleXML, such as comments and processing instructions. It also provides a much richer set of manipulation functions, allowing you to rearrange nodes and choose how to represent text content, for instance. The tradeoff is a fairly complex API, with a large number of classes and methods; since it implements a standard API (originally developed for manipulating HTML in JavaScript), there may be less of a "natural PHP" feel, but some programmers may be familiar with it from other contexts.

Both interfaces require the full document to be parsed into memory, and effectively wrap up pointers into that parsed representation; you can even switch between the two wrappers with  `simplexml_import_dom()` and `dom_import_simplexml()`, for instance to add a "missing" feature to SimpleXML using a function from the DOM API. For larger documents, the "pull-based" [XMLReader](http://php.net/manual/en/book.xmlreader.php) or the "event-based" [XML Parser](http://php.net/manual/en/book.xml.php) may be more appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

SimpleXML is, as name states, simple parser for XML content, and nothing else. You cannot parse, let's say standard html content. It's easy and quick, and therefore a great tool for creating simple applications.

DOM extension, on other side, is much more powerful. It enables you to parse almost any DOM document, including html, xhtml, xml. It enables you to open, write and even correct output code, supports xpath and overall more manipulation.
Therefore, its usage is much more complicated, because library is quite complex, and that makes it a perfect tool for bigger projects where heavy data manipulation is needed.

Hope that answers your question :)

Comment: It's also worth noting that you can use both SimpleXML functions and DOM functions on the same document -- see the example from Jeff M on the [dom_import_simplexml](http://php.net/manual/en/function.dom-import-simplexml.php) manual page. I've used this to do most of my processing using SimpleXML, but do a couple of trickier things using DOM (e.g. creating a CDATA section), all operating on the same underlying document.

Comment: What limitations are you talking about wrt namespaces?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php,
http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php

A glance at methods list will be sufficient :>

Comment: Actually, no it's not. Can you please elaborate on those limitations?

Comment: okay, for example, let's look at http://www.php.net/manual/en/domelement.getattributens.php. SimpleXML just doesn't provide easy enough solution like this. I mean, it can be done, using more code, but is that its purpose? I'd rather just use dom.

Comment: I was talking about the namespace limitations you refer to in your answer. Unless you worded that sentence wrong and you were talking about another kind of limitations: *"It heavily supports namespaces, while simpleXML has certain limitations."* -- Wrt your example, are you aware of SimpleXMLElement::attributes() ? It seems to me that it does pretty much the same thing using a comparable amount of keystrokes.

Comment: Well I have to admit, my mistake ... I clearly wasn't aware of $ns parameter in SimpleXMLElement::attributes() :)

Editing my comment now :)