# How can I download using PHP a XML file redirected in some weird way?

Tags: php, xml, curl, file-get-contents

The file which I'm trying to download from my PHP script is this one:

```
http://www.navarra.es/appsext/DescargarFichero/default.aspx?codigoAcceso=OpenData&fichero=Farmacias/Farmacias.xml
```

But I can't do it using neither `file_get_contents()` nor `cURL`. I'm getting the error `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`

Any idea how to do it?

Thanks a lot, Pablo.

Updated to add the code:

```
$url = "http://www.navarra.es/appsext/DescargarFichero/default.aspx?codigoAcceso=OpenData&fichero=Farmacias/Farmacias.xml";
$simple = simplexml_load_file(file_get_contents($url));
foreach ($simple->farmacia as $farmacia)
{
    var_dump($farmacia);
}
```

And **the solution** thanks to @Gordon:

```
$url = "http://www.navarra.es/appsext/DescargarFichero/default.aspx?codigoAcceso=OpenData&fichero=Farmacias/Farmacias.xml";
$file = file_get_contents($url, FALSE, stream_context_create(array('http' => array('user_agent' => 'php' ))));
$simple = simplexml_load_string($file);
```

Comment: Please show your PHP code that's failing.

Comment: I have updated it with the code. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You dont need `cURL`, nor `file_get_contents` to load XML into any of [PHP's DOM Based XML parsers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/best-methods-to-parse-html/3577662#3577662).

However, in your particular case, the issue seems to be that the server expects a user agent in the http request. If the user agent is not set in your php.ini, you can use the [libxml functions](http://de.php.net/manual/en/book.libxml.php) and provide it as a [stream context](http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.stream-context-create.php):

```
libxml_set_streams_context(
    stream_context_create(
        array(
            'http' => array(
                'user_agent' => 'php'            
            )
        )
    )
);

$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->load('http://www.navarra.es/app…/Farmacias.xml');
echo $dom->saveXml();
```

[Live Demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/cu7mOw)

If you dont want to parse the XML file afterwards, you can use `file_get_contents` as well. You can pass the stream context as the third argument:

```
echo file_get_contents(
    'http://www.navarra.es/apps…/Farmacias.xml',
    FALSE,
    stream_context_create(
        array(
            'http' => array(
                'user_agent' => 'php'            
            )
        )
    )
);
```

[Live Demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/a7h8Dk)

Comment: .. or you could set the user agent with `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Googlebot/2.1...");`

Comment: @please yes, that would work, too. But tbh, I find cURL completely overkill for this.

Comment: Thanks @Gordon, it works perfectly. By your answer I understand that you recommend me to use DOM or XMLReader instead of SimpleXML?

Comment: @Puigcerber I prefer DOM over SimpleXML for the reasons mentioned in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4803063/what-the-difference-between-phps-dom-and-simplexml-extensions/4803264#4803264 and use SimpleXml only for very simple XML files. DOM offers more control. XmlReader is a different kind of parser for different UseCases, namely huge files and memory limited environments. If you can find the time, try out all of them and see which you like best.

Comment: Thanks @Gordon, I will have a look to it.

Comment: Hey @Gordon, could you have a look to my new answer? Thanks a lot.

Comment: @pleasedontbelong do I have to use it like you said or like this `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Googlebot/2.1 (http://www.googlebot.com/bot.html)");`? Thanks.

Comment: @Puigcerber mine was just an exemple =P you can set the user agent to any agent that you want, it could be a google bot, or a mozilla agent =) cheers!

Comment: @Puigcerber the user agent can be anything that identifies the requesting side. It doesnt have to be a browser. See my answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6002513/i-need-to-write-a-web-crawler-for-specific-user-agent-please-help/6002719#6002719 and/or RFC1945 and/or http://www.useragentstring.com/pages/PHP/

Answer (score 0):

I have been using the solution given for @Gordon and it was working perfectly in localhost:

```
$url = "http://www.navarra.es/appsext/DescargarFichero/default.aspx?codigoAcceso=OpenData&fichero=Farmacias/Farmacias.xml";
$file = file_get_contents($url, FALSE, stream_context_create(array('http' =>array('user_agent' => 'php' ))));
$simple = simplexml_load_string($file);
```

But when I have uploaded all the files to the server... surprise, as always. I started to get the error **URL file-access is disabled in the server configuration in** so I have changed all the `file_get_contents()` for this code which I have found [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php#55922):

```
function get_content($url)
{
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Googlebot/2.1...");

ob_start();

curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close ($ch);
$string = ob_get_contents();

ob_end_clean();

return $string;
}
```

Would you think is it a good approach?

Thanks, Pablo.

Comment: if you do `curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);` you dont need to buffer the output. Just do `$content = curl_exec()`.