# I need to write a web crawler for specific user agent

Tags: php, web-crawler

I need to write a web crawler, and want to be able to crawl using a known user agent.  For example, I want my crawler to act as an iphone to crawl the mobile site of a website, then crawl again using Mozilla PC agent, etc.

That way, Ill be able to crawl every "type" of site (mobile & PC).  However, I also want to be able to set my crawler's user agent, so webmasters also see in their stats that it's a crawler that visited their whole website, not real users.

So my question is, do you guys know how to set a mobile agent + a crawler agent at the same time, in PHP?  Is it even possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please refer to [RFC1945](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1945#section-10.15) for how a [User Agent](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/User_agent) should be formed:

> **10.15 User-Agent**
>
> The User-Agent request-header field contains information about the
> user agent originating the request. This is for statistical purposes,
> the tracing of protocol violations, and automated recognition of user
> agents for the sake of tailoring responses to avoid particular user
> agent limitations. Although it is not required, user agents should
> include this field with requests. The field can contain multiple
> product tokens (Section 3.7) and comments identifying the agent and
> any subproducts which form a significant part of the user agent. By
> convention, the product tokens are listed in order of their
> significance for identifying the application.
>
> ```
>  User-Agent     = "User-Agent" ":" 1*( product | comment )
> ```
>
> Example:
>
> ```
>   User-Agent: CERN-LineMode/2.15 libwww/2.17b3
> ```

So what you put there is more or less up to you. You could pose to be a GoogleBot-Mobile:

- https://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?answer=1061943

or pose as an iPhone and add your own stuff

```
Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; U; CPU iPhone OS) (compatible; MyBot/1.0; +http://about.my/bot")
```

Comment: You are just awsome.  This is EXACTLY what I needed.  Thanks a lot for your help.  Its greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 0):

```
    function crawl($url){

        $headers[]  = "User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.9.2.13) Gecko/20101203 Firefox/3.6.13"; // <-- this is user agent
        $headers[]  = "Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8";
        $headers[]  = "Accept-Language:en-us,en;q=0.5";
        $headers[]  = "Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate";
        $headers[]  = "Accept-Charset:ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7";
        $headers[]  = "Keep-Alive:115";
        $headers[]  = "Connection:keep-alive";
        $headers[]  = "Cache-Control:max-age=0";

        $curl = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_ENCODING, "gzip");
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        $data = curl_exec($curl);
        curl_close($curl);
        return $data;

    }

echo crawl("http://www.google.com"); // revenge
```

You can always use eg http://m.facebook.com/ w/o user agent, although most of websites redirect user to proper content by reading user agent.

Comment: Yeah, I know how to set a user agent to a specific browser and platform.  However, how is it possible to also set the user agent to let web servers know we are a crawler.

Comment: webservers dont care what type of traffic it is, the script or .htaccess is whats redirecting based on useragent,ip,referrer ect

Comment: Lawrence: no, I really need to let webservers know that my crawler is a crawler and not a real user because I want them to be able to block my bot using their .htaccess file.  I also need to be able to set my user agent to mobile to that I can crawl mobile sites as well.

Comment: @Steve Rodrigue, nobody cares if it's a bot or a user as long as you do no harm to website. You can write whatever you want in User-Agent but that doesn't mean anything. Many bots set Google User-Agent, only way to check is to run gethostbyaddr (PHP) to see if it's google.com

Comment: you cant have it both ways, if a site is checking a useragent to redirect to mobile site then your own wont be detected as a mobile one, but if you then change it your basically bypassing that anyway.

Comment: @Steve: Read the robots.txt file in the root of the website to enable people to block your crawler. That's what it is for.

Comment: @PeeHaa the last 20k bot that crawled my site forgot to check

Comment: PeeHaa: this is exactly what I wanted to do.  But since I cannot set the user agent to mobile + set my crawler's name inside the agent, how should user set their robot.txt file to block my crawler?

Comment: @Lawrence. Steve is going to build one himself so he can check can't he?

Comment: @Steve if you use Lawrence's answer you can just add your custom User Agent string