# use file_get_contents

Tags: php, file-get-contents

I use file_get_content to leech rss.

I try use:

```
echo file_get_contents("http://vnexpress.net/gl/xa-hoi/2011/11/mot-so-bo-truong-the-hien-su-ne-tranh-trach-nhiem/");
```

Result is content of page

And I try use

```
echo file_get_content("http://hcm.24h.com.vn/ban-tre-cuoc-song/noi-doi-de-quyen-ru-chang-c64a418748.html");
```

Result is a blank page. why I can't get it? this page not allow file_get_contents function? sorry I bad english, please allow my question. thanks

Comment: this is likely a network issue, or the hosting site blocking your access (from your network or ip)

Comment: This is not an RSS feed. The RSS feed is located at http://www.24h.com.vn/upload/rss/bantrecuocsong.rss. See if http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5975213/how-can-i-download-using-php-a-xml-file-redirected-in-some-weird-way/5975340#5975340 solves your problem.

Answer (score 4):

Try using `file_get_contents` instead of `file_get_content`.

Answer (score 3):

You're missing a s. It should be

```
echo file_get_contents("http://hcm.24h.com.vn/ban-tre-cuoc-song/noi-doi-de-quyen-ru-chang-c64a418748.html");
```

Comment: This still blank page. demo: http://kiengiangit.com/@forum/functions/tinhyeu-24h.php

Answer (score 1):

First of all it's **file_get_contents**, not **file_get_content**.
Secondly it's not going to work with a http link.

> http://vnexpress.net/gl/xa-hoi/2011/11/mot-so-bo-truong-the-hien-su-ne-tranh-trach-nhiem/

should be something like

> /home/48564568/public_html/gl/xa-hoi/2011/11/mot-so-bo-truong-the-hien-su-ne-tranh-trach-nhiem/

depending on your server.

To find what the link should be, try to include a nonexisting file like so

> include(somethingrandom.php);

and you will receive an error notice that */the/path/you/need/somethingrandom.php* doesn't exist.

Comment: please describe why file_get_contents wont work with http link

Comment: It's a security measure. If anyone could include a remote php file one could include it on their website and have your server execute the PHP code.You can get around this security measure by setting allow_url_include to ON on php.ini, but I wouldn't recommend it because of the formerly addressed security leak.

Answer (score 1):

PHP documentation clearly states that file_get_contents supports remote files, but you need to enable the **allow_url_fopen** configuration option. Many sites (in my experience) avoid delivering content if the user_agent directive is not set. You should also try to set this value to a valid user agent string.

From https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php

> Example #1 Get and output the source of the homepage of a website
>
> ```
> <?php
> $homepage = file_get_contents('http://www.example.com/');
> echo $homepage;
> ?>
> ```

From https://www.php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-fopen

> Here's a short explanation of the configuration directives.
>
> **allow_url_fopen**  boolean
>
> This option enables the URL-aware fopen
> wrappers that enable accessing URL object like files. Default wrappers
> are provided for the access of remote files using the ftp or http
> protocol, some extensions like zlib may register additional wrappers.

There could be a lot of things (outside of the scope of this answer) that could be preventing you from pulling the file, but I have found multiple times that just setting the user_agent directive to a valid string will do the trick.