# PHP change DOM useragent

Tags: php, url, dom, domdocument, domxpath

I have this simple code to get the title of any page

```
<?php
    $doc = new DOMDocument();
    @$doc->loadHTMLFile('http://www.facebook.com');
    $xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
    echo $xpath->query('//title')->item(0)->nodeValue."\n";
?>
```

It is working fine on all pages that I have tried but not in Facebook.

When I try in Facebook it is not showing `Welcome to Facebook - Log In, Sign Up or Learn More`, but it is showing `Update Your Browser | Facebook`.

I think there is a problem with useragent. So is there a way to change the useragent or is there any other solution for this?

Comment: i would load the html using curl and pass to DOMDocument

Comment: And how can I do it. Is there any example code?

Comment: check below for my answer

Comment: Not the same problem but answers your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5975213/how-can-i-download-using-php-a-xml-file-redirected-in-some-weird-way/5975340#5975340

Comment: @Gordon How can I get only the title?

Comment: `$doc->getElementsByTagName('title')->item(0)->nodeValue;`

Comment: Facebook has no `title` tag. that's why it's not working for you see my comment below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the user agent in php.ini, without the need for curl. Just use the below lines before you load the DOMDocument

```
$agent = "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)";
ini_set('user_agent', $agent);
```

And then your code:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
@$doc->loadHTMLFile('http://www.facebook.com');
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
echo $xpath->query('//title')->item(0)->nodeValue."\n";
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no direct method to change the user agent in `DOMDocument`. You can use curl to retrieve the html and then pass on to `DOMDocument`. Here is how to retrieve data from `curl`

```
$ch = curl_init();
$timeout = 5;
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.13) Gecko/20080311 Firefox/2.0.0.13');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

You can pass it to `DomDocument` using the method below.

```
$dom = new DomDocument();
$dom->loadHtml($data);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
echo $xpath->query('//title')->item(0)->nodeValue."\n";
```

Comment: How can I get only the title. `$data` is showing the whole page?

Comment: I tried this. It is working good on other pages but again not in facebook. It is showing this error `Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\localhost\htdocs\title\index.php on line 17`

Comment: The last one `echo $xpath->query('//title')->item(0)->nodeValue."\n";`

Comment: check the source facebook has no `title` tag @Enve

Comment: I checked from `view-source:https://www.facebook.com` in Google Chrome. There is a title tag `<title id="pageTitle">Welcome to Facebook - Log In, Sign Up or Learn More</title>`

Comment: that `title` is not a root element it's inside `noscript`. change your query to something like `echo $xpath->query('//*/title')->item(0)->nodeValue."\n";`

Answer (score 0):

Facebook probably doesn't want people to scrape their site. What you can do on the other hand is to `cURL` it, but provide a legitimate user agent (perhaps your own, `$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']` and then provide that result into `DOMDocument`.

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'www.facebook.com');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);

$dom = new DomDocument();
$dom->loadHtml(curl_exec($ch));
```