# SimpleXML access separated text nodes

Tags: php, simplexml

I have an XML file like the following:

```
...
<MyElement>Introduction:<br />
   ...
</MyElement>
...
```

Are there any way to return "Introduction:" and the rest after `</br>` of that element?

I am using PHP and SimpleXML. Naively use `echo $document->MyElement` shows "Introduction:...", which mixed up the Introduction line and the content.

Comment: you have to include that inside `[[CDATA` because you have a `<br/>`

Comment: However unusual it is, that is legal XML. `<br />` is a legal XML tag (as long as the DTD or schema allows it), and XML tags can appear within a text node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SimpleXML does not have the concept of text-nodes as you might know it from DOMDocument (see as well with [this comparison table](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17557961/367456)).

So in PHP the option is that you import the `<MyElement>` element into DOM and you then do the operation there:

```
 # prints "Introduction:"

 echo dom_import_simplexml($myElement)->firstChild->data;
 //                                          ^      
 //                                          `- is DOMText
```

Answer (score 0):

to read your xml string use the following code, change `root_element` to match your root element name.

```
$content = simplexml_load_string($xml_string);
echo $content->root_element->MyElement
```

Comment: I have already said in the question, that will mix up the introduction part and the content.