# How to parse the XML file in php?

Tags: php, xml, rss

I am trying to parse the rss xml feeder, but there is some content is missing while am parsing. I have attached my rss feed below and the response of parsing, please suggest me if is there any other way?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<rss version="2.0">
<channel>
<item>
<ids>701</ids>
<post_date>2015-10-30 12:51:30</post_date>
<post_content><blockquote>I personally feel that there is a need to re?invent the very dynamic of contemporary art, to approach it afresh...     </blockquote>

Since 2008, the Devi Art Foundation has been making waves as a unique non?profit centre for contemporary artistic practice in India.

<strong>Heading:</strong> As founder of the Devi Art Foundation, you pioneered a unique and avant?

<strong>Anupam Poddar: </strong>There are many factors that culminated in the Foundation being established.
 </post_content> 
 </item>
 </channel>
```

And the response is like this

```
 Array
 (
 [@attributes] => Array
    (
        [version] => 2.0
    )

 [channel] => Array
    (
        [item] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (

                        [ids] => 701
                        [post_date] => 2015-10-30 12:51:30
                        [post_content] => Array
                            (
                                [blockquote] => I personally feel that there is a need to re?invent the very dynamic of contemporary art, to approach it afresh...
                                [strong] => Array
                                    (
                                        [0] => Heading:
                                        [1] => Anupam Poddar: 

                                    )
                            )
                    )
            )
        )
      )
```

And my parsing method is

```
  $xml   = simplexml_load_string($details, "SimpleXMLElement",        LIBXML_NOCDATA);
  $json  = json_encode($xml);
  $array = json_decode($json, TRUE);
```

Comment: I realized my answer was busted (sorry, wrote that on a mobile device), so I deleted it. SimpleXML doesn't support accessing the data between nodes. Check out the solution/workaround in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20177247/2057919).

Answer (score 0):

If you're missing some content it's caused by poor design of this feed (each value should be bordered by an element) so it can't be completly parsed via simplexml_load_* functions.

If you need to use this feed you need to parse it by some regex function or maybe there are some libraries which can parse those feeds too.