# how read the data from XML file using php

Tags: php, html, xml, file

I Have a XML file which have data's in it,i want to reading the XML file get values and display the values,i am trying to display RECIPIENT_NUM and TEMPLATE ,but now i able to display only the TEMPLATE but i can't able to display the RECIPIENT_NUM.below is my code can any one guide me to display the RECIPIENT_NUM,thanks

XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<DOCUMENT>
   <VERSION>2.0</VERSION>
   <INVOICE_NUM>33</INVOICE_NUM>
   <PIN>14567894</PIN>
   <MESSAGE_TYPE>INSTANT_SEND</MESSAGE_TYPE>
   <COUNTRY_CODE>xxxxxxx</COUNTRY_CODE>
   <TEMPLATE>Dear Mrs Braem, this is a message from xxxxxxx. Kindly call us regarding your cleaning appoitnment tomorrow at 9.30. Thanks and Regards</TEMPLATE>
   <DATABASEINFO>
      <DATABASE_NAME>xxxxxx</DATABASE_NAME>
      <CLINIC_ID>1</CLINIC_ID>
   </DATABASEINFO>
   <MESSAGES>
      <MESSAGE>
         <SEND_DATE>2013-12-15</SEND_DATE>
         <ENTITY_ID>0</ENTITY_ID>
         <RECIPIENT_NUM>xxxxxxx</RECIPIENT_NUM>
         <MESSAGE_PARAMS />
      </MESSAGE>
   </MESSAGES>
   <CSUM>ffd6c84a1a89a0f2ebc8b1dc8ea1f4fb</CSUM>
</DOCUMENT>
```

PHP

```
<html>
<body>

<?php
$xml=simplexml_load_file("/data/data/www/Message.xml");
print_r($xml);

echo $xml->TEMPLATE . "<br>";
echo $xml->RECIPIENT_NUM."<br>";
?>  

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to look at the structure of the XML, you need to do

```
echo $xml->MESSAGES->MESSAGE->RECIPIENT_NUM."<br>";
```

Answer (score 3):

This works for me,

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file("/data/data/www/Message.xml");
foreach($xml->children() as $key => $children) {
  print((string)$children->TEMPLATE); echo "<br>";
  print((string)$children->RECIPIENT_NUM); echo "<br>";
  // Remaining codes here.
}
```

The simplexml_load_file() returns xml nodes as object, each element in that object can be read using children() and can be retrived as string value using the above code.

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bcode-based-answers) an explanation really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion Şivā SankĂr, I have updated with a description.

Answer (score 1):

DOM is more complex, but can do everything, try to visit this [DOM vs. SimpleXML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4803063/whats-the-difference-between-phps-dom-and-simplexml-extensions)

 
Try this:

```
$xml = new DOMDocument();
$xml->load('/data/data/www/Message.xml');
$data = array (           
      'template'       => $xml->getElementsByTagName('TEMPLATE')->item(0)->nodeValue,
       'recipient_num' => $xml->getElementsByTagName('RECIPIENT_NUM')->item(0)->nodeValue          
        );         
 var_dump($data);
```

Comment: DOM isn't more complex, just use DOMXpath: `$template = $xpath->evaluate('string(//TEMPLATE)')`.

Answer (score 0):

When you load the xml file using the php `simplexml_load_file` function to a variable. The veritable becomes an object.

```
<?php 
$xml=simplexml_load_file("/data/data/www/Message.xml");
?>
```

So, in your case, the `$xml` variable becomes a multi-level object where every elements of xml file are key of the object. Like: **TEMPLATE**, **PIN**, **COUNTRY_CODE**, **MESSAGES** etc.

To access the data of the element, need to call like this bellow code.

```
echo $xml->TEMPLATE . "<br>";
```

Once you don this code, you will get the value under the **TEMPLATE** element.

But, as `$xml` is a multi-level object, to access the element under the **MESSAGES**, under **MESSAGE** like **RECIPIENT_NUM**, you have to code like bellow.

```
echo $xml->MESSAGES->MESSAGE->RECIPIENT_NUM."<br>";
```

Here,
`MESSAGES` is the key of `$xml` object.
`MESSAGE` is the key of `MESSAGES`.
`RECIPIENT_NUM` is the key of `MESSAGE`.

Finally, you will get the value of key element `RECIPIENT_NUM` = `xxxxx`

You can also access the value using php `foreach` loop.