# Get all value from multiple sub child xml data using php

Tags: php, xml

I got problem getting value from xml data, here is my data

```
                [a] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                    (
                        [b] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                            (
                                [id] => 123
                                [name] => Daughter
                                [a] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                    (
                                        [b] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                            (
                                                [id] => 234
                                                [name] => Mom 
                                                [c] => 1
                                                [a] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                                    (
                                                        [b] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                                            (
                                                                [id] => 345
                                                                [name] => Grandma
                                                            )

                                                    )

                                            )

                                    )

                            )

                    )
```

How I can get this data

> 123Daughter
>
> 234Mom
>
> 345Grandma

The sub child is lot not only 3 level, try to read this one [XML File - Get specific child nodes in unlimited node depths](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27579760/xml-file-get-specific-child-nodes-in-unlimited-node-depths) but still can't understand, anyone can help me, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the [xpath function](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.xpath.php):

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($xml);
foreach ($xml->xpath('//b') as $item) {
    echo $item->id . $item->name . PHP_EOL;
}
```

or if you want print just name:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($xml);
foreach ($xml->xpath('//name') as $name) {
    echo $name . PHP_EOL;
}
```

code snippet: https://3v4l.org/tYeBi#output